# RGB Integer Values to Color Values

Tags: java, colors

I have RGB integer values as `-16776961` and `-16121651`.

How can I get the Color values of the Integers as `java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=205]`and`java.awt.Color[r=10,g=0,b=205]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `Color` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int%29) that takes an `int` as parameter (the alpha value is defaulted to 255).

```
Color c = new Color(-16121651); //java.awt.Color[r=10,g=0,b=205]
```

Then you can just call `getBlue()`, `getRed()` or `getGreen()` to get the specific value of the color you want.